# Oxyplot: logarithmic stem plot is upside down

Tags: c#, charts, logarithm, oxyplot, yaxis

I would like to visualize 1024 values in a stem plot with a logarithmic y-scale. With a linear scale it works fine, but with a logarithmic scale the graph looks wierd. Is there a bug in my code or in oxyplot?

My stem plot looks like this:
[reversed stem plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGTtm.png)

This is my source code:

```
        var plotModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Stem Plot" };           
        plotModel.Axes.Clear();
        if (yScalingType==(int)YScalingType.log)
        {                
            LogarithmicAxis axisY = new LogarithmicAxis               
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Left,
                MajorStep = 20,
                UseSuperExponentialFormat = false,
                Base = 10
            };
            axisY.AbsoluteMaximum = 1000;
            axisY.AbsoluteMinimum = 0;
            plotModel.Axes.Add(axisY); 
        }
        var series = new StemSeries();
        plotModel.Series.Add(series);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
            series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, 100.0));
```

Comment: The same happens if I use column plot instead of stem plot.

Comment: Well this is puzzling! A bug maybe? Have you checked on the github repo if there is a known issue with stemseries? https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue regarding this on the github page of OxyPlot. As suggested by a user (see [here](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/740)), a temporary fix could be to set the `Base` value of your series to 1 (`var series = new StemSeries { Base = 1d };`)... the graph is then displayed properly!

Comment: Glad to hear :)